# Use DispatcherTimer without WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use a `DispatcherTimer` without WPF. It doesn't, the tick event is not triggered. See code sample below. Is there a way to make it work?

Why am I trying to do it? I am implementing a unit test for a class that hooks in my view model. That class uses the DispatcherTimer.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer;
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
        timer.Tick += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        timer.Start();
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DispatcherTimer doesn't work in Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351473/dispatchertimer-doesnt-work-in-console)

Comment: Why don't you use a `System.Timers.Timer`? It makes no sense to use a `DispatcherTimer` when there is no dispatcher...If you want to be able unit test your view model, you should mock away the `DispatcherTimer` dependency.

Comment: mm8: Yeah, mocking the timer. Thought about that. But my aim was to really test the timer as I had situations (in WPF) where the timer didn't start. I now call the Timer.Tick() function directly from my unit test, which has a similar effect.

Comment: @Kyle: I saw that article already. Thank you. Seems I have use some other strategy in my unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use DispatcherTimer because there is no dispatcher in console apps. [Take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351473/dispatchertimer-doesnt-work-in-console)